# Load testing using jmeter along with influxdb and grafana

Tags: server, jmeter, grafana, influxdb, master-slave

I want to do the load testing using JMeter. I want to give load 24k users at time that is bit difficult because i am getting heap size error and JMeter is not responding could you please suggest how to do the master and slave configuration along with influx dB and Grafana setup.

I want to know that how to analyze the load testing test result means what are the factors i need to analyze and conclude the result .

how to check Server side monitorization ?

Answer (score 0):

- > please suggest how to do the master and slave configuration along with influx dB and Grafana setup

  There are no extra steps required

  - just [install JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) onto remote machines
  - perform [RMI SSL configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) if needed (or disable it)
  - perform [RMI ports configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) (if you cannot use defaults - amend them and open in firewall)
  - launch JMeter slave process on load generator machines
  - list all the slave machines under `remote_hosts` property in [user.properties file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- > I want to know that how to analyze the load testing test result means what are the factors i need to analyze and conclude the result

  it depends on the nature of the application you're testing, mainly people are correlating increasing load with increasing throughput and if the load increases and the throughput remains the same or goes down it indicates  a performance problem. Make sure to understand what each metric listed under [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) means
- > how to check Server side monitorization

  ask around, there could be something implemented already and you can just add this information to your Grafana dashboard. If not - you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) or [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon#sshmon-samples-collector-) for this.